# Need Your Advise on Recurring Payments With Paypal API on PHP

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I'm trying to tame the PayPal API with moderate success. I use PHP for sending the request and processing the response. So far I've managed to compose a valid array containing the request parameters and send it to the Paypal for validation. The request goes through validation and returns transaction token as expected. Here's my array:

```
$requestParams = array(

'RETURNURL'  => 'http://www.myurl.com/#success',
'CANCELURL'  => 'http://www.myurl.com/#cancel',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 30,
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT'  => '10',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => 'USD',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'  => '20',
'ALLOWNOTE' => 1,
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1'  => 'Black kitten',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1'  => 'Nice and fluffy cute guy',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1'  => '1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1'  => '10',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'  => 'Ginger kitten',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'  => 'Super cute ginger dude',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'  => '1',
'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'  => '10'

);
```

**THE QUESTION**

I want to send the same request but to form a **recurring payment**. Which means I want to charge the user's PayPal account every month. I was surfing throught PayPal API docs, but the way it's written seems super confusing for me and provides no answers whatsoever.

Maybe I should just insert another parameter to the **$requestParams** or maybe I should compose a completely different array or what? Please assist!

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wrote [an article about this](http://www.angelleye.com/php-tools-creating-paypal-recurring-payments-system/) a few days ago.  It's a pretty quick run-through of the process so if you have more questions let me know, but I'd definitely recommend taking a look as it lays out everything you'll need to do, and it does it with my class library which makes this all very simple for you.

Comment: thanks man! I'll give it a read and come back to you with the questions. Cheers!

Comment: You really should post the answer here

Comment: Andrew! I read your article and downloaded the library you provided. I opened the example file _CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php_ where it seems like the request is formed. There's a part of the request array called `$CCDetails` it includes credit card data and marked as _required_. What if I want user to pay without entering the credit card data on my side, or what if user wants to pay with PayPal money? Is there any way to form the request with no payment details? PS: If you check my initial array it contains only the product details and requires no payment details whatsoever and it works.

Comment: That's a little misleading.  The parameters marked required for that set of fields are only required when actually including those parameters.  If you leave CCDetails out altogether that would mean you're just doing it at the end of an Express Checkout flow, and then a TOKEN would be required instead of the CCDetails.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to implement recurring payment is using Express Checkout with creation of Billing Agreement and Reference Transactions. You can find details in official documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) and [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/).